# Time control for specific applications on OS X

Tags: macos, parental-controls

Is there a simple way to limit the use of a specific application to a certain amount of time (for instance one hour per day)?

To be more specific, I use a Macbook with OS X 10.10, on which there are several accounts, one for me and one for my daughter, who is a Parental Controls account.

Apparently, it is possible with the Apple's Parental Controls system to put time limits on the use on the computer, and also to block specific applications, but not to combine those two applications, blocking one application at certain time or for certain duration. So how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The only program I could find with this capability is Watcher, but it has very poor reviews from users.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/9037/watcher