# How to lock an App/Game with terminal?

Tags: terminal, high-sierra

My son uses my iMac for school stuff and some gaming. I have caught him playing games during school hours when he isn't supposed to be playing games.

I know that I can use parental controls to set this up, but we both just use the same user. (so he knows the passwords.)

Is there a way I can use terminal to "lock" the game (or application) so that it won't open unless I unlock it via terminal?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327383/263848

Comment: Yjere is a reason there can be multiple users - to allow each user different permissions. So in this case create a new user for yourself with admin rights using a new password. Then make the existing user a normal one and put it under parental control.

Comment: That would make a great answer, Mark